# using Autocomplete by ProgressiveInput in react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using `ProgressiveInput` to autocomplete in react-native. I am calling a function `searchLocation(query)` onChangeText() which returns a `ListView` of suggestions.
Here is my code :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProgressiveInput from 'react-native-progressive-input';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
  rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.id !== r2.id,
});
export default class FirstProject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
      value: '',
      query:'',
    };
  }

 searchLocation(query) {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true, value: query });
  fetch('https://reactnativecode.000webhostapp.com/FruitsList.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "name":query
  })
}).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
      }, function() {
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  renderRow(prediction) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.onListItemClicked(prediction)}
        style={styles.listItem}
      >
        <Text>{prediction}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
  renderSeparator() {
    return <View style={styles.listItemSeparator} />;
  }

  onInputCleared() {
    this.setState({
      value: '',
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
    });
  }

onListItemClicked(prediction) {
    this.setState({
      value: prediction,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
      isLoading: true,
    });
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ProgressiveInput
          value={this.state.value}
          style={styles.progressiveInput}
          isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
          oonChangeText={(text) => this.searchLocation(text)}
          onInputCleared={this.onInputCleared}
        />
        <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
         <ListView
            enableEmptySections
            style={styles.listView}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow}
            renderSeparator={this.renderSeparator}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  progressiveInput: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  listViewContainer: {
    flex: 0,
  },
  listView: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    margin: 10,
  },
  listItem: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  listItemSeparator: {
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: 'lightgrey',
  },
});
```

But i am getting the following error :-
[image]

Please suggest how can i use `ProgressiveInput` in this case.